# Linq Query to Compare with List of string values

Tags: c#, linq

I need to compare and get the matching values from a string list with LINQ. Have a look at my code.

**Code**

```
Split = Id.Split(',');
List<string> uids = new List<string>(Split);
var model = (from xx in Db.ItemWeedLogs
                where xx.ItemNo == uids   
                // I need to pass a string list to extract the matching record.
                select xx).ToList();
```

Comment: omg so late :/ this people so fast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this :

```
var model = (from xx in Db.ItemWeedLogs
                     where uids.Contains(xx.ItemNo)
                     select xx).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
where uid.contains(xx.ItemNo)
```

Comment: @Dheyv You are more than welcome. You should accept Wahid's answer (he was first and clearer ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is much more faster and clear.

```
var model = Db.ItemWeedLogs
              .Join(Id.Split(','), di => di.ItemNo, si => si, (d, s) => new {d})
              .ToList();
```

Comment: +1 , depending on the relative sizes of the collections, building up a dictionnary might be a good option too